# Passing data between 1 basic class and 2 WPF window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

First of all, I'm new to C# and .NET development. I was working on a console app and decided to switch to graphical using WPF. Everything was fine with the console app but I'm having troubles right now. So basically, I have this window:

[Window 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4MQD.png)

When I click on the "Add Task" button, this new window opens: [Window 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mTZ6.png). I want to perform a sequential series of save tasks (the app is made to copy directories and eventually encrypt them if the users wants to) and in order to do that, I'm saving all the copy parameters in lists of string in a third class where there's a method to run through them and execute copies.

What I want to do is display all the information the user entered in the Window1 in the datagrid, select the save tasks I want to perform and then call the method that copies when I click on the "Launch Save" button but I can't figure how. I can't retrieve the data stored in the lists in the third class with the Window2 from the Window1, it seems even like I can't store multiple save parameters in the lists I made, only one at a time. Tbh idk what to do, I've been searching for hours for a way to do that but I don't find a clue. I'm pretty sure that the way I'm coding is wrong and that I'm missing some logic/reasoning things that are important (or just a lack of knowledge idk) so that's why I came here asking for help.

Here's the code of the window1:

```
public partial class NewSave : Window
{
    SeqSave sqSv1 = new SeqSave();

    public NewSave()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<SeqSave> caracSave = new List<SeqSave>();

        if (sqSv1.savedNamesList.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < sqSv1.savedNamesList.Count; i++)
            {
                caracSave.Add(new SeqSave() { SaveTaskName = sqSv1.savedNamesList[i], SourcePath = sqSv1.srcPathList[i], DestinationPath = sqSv1.dstPathList[i], SaveType = sqSv1.saveTypeList[i], Backup = sqSv1.didBackupList[i] });
            }

            saveListsDisplay.ItemsSource = caracSave;
        }
    }

    private void BusinessSoftware(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void AddTask(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AddTask aT1 = new AddTask();
        aT1.Show();
    }

    private void saveListsDisplay_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void LaunchSave(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //for(int i = 0; i < sqSv1.savedNamesList.Count; i++)
        //{
        //    Console.WriteLine(sqSv1.savedNamesList[i] + "\n"
        //        + sqSv1.srcPathList[i] + "\n"
        //        + sqSv1.dstPathList[i] + "\n"
        //        + sqSv1.saveTypeList[i] + "\n"
        //        + sqSv1.didBackupList[i]);
        //}
        sqSv1.launchSave();
    }
}
```

And here's the code of the Window2:

```
public partial class AddTask : Window
{
    List<string> listExtension = new List<string>();
    SeqSave sqSv1 = new SeqSave();

    public AddTask()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void GetSourcePath(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog sourcePath = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        DialogResult result = sourcePath.ShowDialog();
        string strSourcePath = sourcePath.SelectedPath;
        sqSv1.srcPathList.Add(strSourcePath);

        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(strSourcePath);

        foreach (FileInfo f in dirInfo.GetFiles())
        {
           if (!listExtension.Contains(f.Extension))
           {
               listExtension.Add(f.Extension);
           }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < listExtension.Count; i++)
        {
            lstB1.Items.Add(listExtension[i]);
        }
    }

    private void GetDestinationPath(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog destinationPath = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        DialogResult result = destinationPath.ShowDialog();
        string strDestinationPath = destinationPath.SelectedPath;
        sqSv1.dstPathList.Add(strDestinationPath);
    }

    private void Encrypt(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void Return(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void Confirm(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        sqSv1.savedNamesList.Add(taskNameProject.Text);

        if (RadioButton1.IsChecked == true)
        {
            sqSv1.saveTypeList.Add("1");

        }
        else if(RadioButton2.IsChecked == true)
        {
            sqSv1.saveTypeList.Add("2");
        }

        if (Checkbox1.IsChecked == true)
        {
            sqSv1.didBackupList.Add(true);
        }
        else
        {
            sqSv1.didBackupList.Add(false);
        }

        MessageBox.Show("Task successfully added.");
        this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to create a new window each time you click "Add task"? I mean wouldn't it better to navigate to some sort of tab / panel / whatever, hosting within the main window so your users would not be confused with lots of these windows.

Comment: You're right, working on it right now.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create public properties in your second form. I added `public` to your code like this. I also added dialog results to both forms.

```
public partial class AddTask : Window
{

    public List<string> ListExtension { get; } = new List<string>();
    public SeqSave SqSv1 { get; }= new SeqSave();

    public AddTask()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void GetSourcePath(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog sourcePath = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        DialogResult result = sourcePath.ShowDialog();
        string strSourcePath = sourcePath.SelectedPath;
        SqSv1.srcPathList.Add(strSourcePath);

        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(strSourcePath);
        foreach (FileInfo f in dirInfo.GetFiles())
        {
           if (!ListExtension.Contains(f.Extension))
           {
               ListExtension.Add(f.Extension);
           }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < ListExtension.Count; i++)
        {
            lstB1.Items.Add(ListExtension[i]);
        }
    }

    private void GetDestinationPath(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog destinationPath = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        DialogResult result = destinationPath.ShowDialog();
        string strDestinationPath = destinationPath.SelectedPath;
        SqSv1.dstPathList.Add(strDestinationPath);
    }

    private void Encrypt(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void Return(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Confirm(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SqSv1.savedNamesList.Add(taskNameProject.Text);

        if (RadioButton1.IsChecked == true)
        {
            SqSv1.saveTypeList.Add("1");

        }else if(RadioButton2.IsChecked == true)
        {
            SqSv1.saveTypeList.Add("2");
        }
        if (Checkbox1.IsChecked == true)
        {
            SqSv1.didBackupList.Add(true);
        }
        else
        {
            SqSv1.didBackupList.Add(false);
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Task successfully added.");
        this.Close();
        DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }
}
```

And then access those in the original form like this:

```
    private void AddTask(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AddTask aT1 = new AddTask();
        DialogResult results = aT1.ShowDialog();
        if(results == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            List<string> listExt = aT1.ListExtension;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you sir! Helped a lot